# Duplicate interface declaration errors when I create MobileSubstrate tweaks

Tags: iphone, ios, cydia

I have a problem about making Mobile Substrate tweaks for iOS 5.

Most tutorial about making Cydia tweaks have this step: "Download private framework headers".
So, I downloaded it from : https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks

Since the private-frameworks are dumped from iOS 3.x, some new methods and variables are not included.

Therefore, I added these variables to my Tweak.xm. And I imported the private-framework-headers too.

For example:

```
#import "/opt/theos/include/UIKit/UIKit2.h"
#import "/opt/theos/include/UIKit/UIKeyboardLayoutStar.h"

@interface UIKeyboardImpl : UIView
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL showsCandidateInline;
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL showsCandidateBar;
@end
```

However, when I compile the tweak, I got these errors:

```
Tweak.xm:45: error: duplicate interface declaration for class ‘UIKeyboardImpl’
Tweak.xm:45: error: redefinition of ‘struct UIKeyboardImpl’
Tweak.xm:45: error: trying to finish struct, but kicked out due to previous parse errors
```

How can I do to fix this problem ?
Should I edit the private framework headers of iOS 3 and add new variables from iOS 5?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a category will fix it.

```
@interface UIKeyboardImpl (YourCategory)
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL showsCandidateInline;
@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL showsCandidateBar;
@end
```